# 'Page not found error' while creating rest-api using django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, django-rest-framework

I declared the URL pattern correctly, but I get 'Page Not Found error' if I go to the 'localhost:8000/rest' URL. here is the code snippet -

```
from myspace import views
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_api import views as rest_api_views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'post', rest_api_views.GetEntryViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('rest/',include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('', include('myspace.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed the '/' in url. Try `localhost:8000/rest/`

Also, I think you need to update the `rest/' path in the urlpatterns

```
#current
path('rest/',include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

#updated
path('rest/', router.urls)
```

this is because currently, you are pointing to `rest_frameworks.urls` instead of the actual URLs.

Additionally, you can instead create the `urls.py` file in the `rest_api` app and move the routers related to the rest app into that.

```
# rest_api/urls.py
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_api import views as rest_api_views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'post', rest_api_views.GetEntryViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Now use this file in the `urls.py` of the project.

```
from myspace import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('rest/',include('rest_api.urls', namespace='rest_api')),
    path('', include('myspace.urls')),
]
```

Comment: I added the '/' in the end ..but still there is the same error.

Comment: Oh yes. I have updated the answer for the resolution of this error

Answer (score 0):

Please Make sure you have **installed** and **configured** it correctly or not.

make sure have you included the URL.
from django.conf.urls import include

[For your reference](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)